# Kali Linux にデフォルトユーザーの情報を入力してもログインできない

Tags: linux

VirtualBoxにKali-Linux-2021.2-virtualbox-amd64をインポートして起動し、ログインしようとしたところ、うまくいきませんでした。

「説明」欄には以下のようにありました。

- Username:kali
- Password:kali
  (US keyboard layout)

ですが、そのように入力しても、「Your password is incorrected. Please try again.」
となってしまいます。

この場合どうすればkali linuxの中に入れるのでしょうか。
何かご教示いただけることがあれば、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Caps Lock がかかって大文字入力になったりしていませんか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ユーザー名が「kali」となっているので、Caps Lockはかかってなさそうです。

Answer (score 0):

Kali-Linux上で「英数」キーを押していたことが原因で、シングルクォーテーションのようなものが入力されていることが原因でした。お騒がせしました